# Lookup in Jython (and Gephi)

Tags: java, jython, lookup

I'm trying to use Gephi Toolkit in Jython, but having problems with it. The code is below:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('gephi-toolkit.jar')
from org.openide.util import Lookup
import org.gephi.project.api.ProjectController as ProjectController

pc = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(ProjectController)
workspace = pc.newProject()

print "done."
```

It never reaches the last line. Instead gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "standalone.py", line 9, in <module>
    workspace = pc.newProject()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'newProject'
```

Apparently, "Lookup.getDefault().lookup(ProjectController)" is returning None. Can anyone tell me why? I found that the following workaround works (which bypasses Lookup):

```
...
import org.gephi.project.impl.ProjectControllerImpl as ProjectControllerImpl
pc = ProjectControllerImpl()
workspace = pc.newProject()
```

I'd like to know more about this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it's because the lookup needs a reference to the java class, not the jython wrapper

try this and see if it works for you,for me at least it returns an instance of org.gephi.project.impl.ProjectControllerImpl

> import sys
>
> from org.openide.util import Lookup
>
> import java.lang.Class
>
> import org.gephi.project.api.ProjectController as ProjectController
>
> pc = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(java.lang.Class.forName("org.gephi.project.api.ProjectController"))
>
> print(pc)

---

> invoke using (change to wherever your gephi is installed)
>
> set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\java\gephi-toolkit-0.7.2014-all\gephi-toolkit.jar
>
> jython.bat gephi_test.jy

you should see something like

C:\jython2.5.2>jython.bat gephi_test.jy

org.gephi.project.impl.ProjectControllerImpl@8ddb93

Comment: Thanks! That definitely makes sense, but I couldn't make it work. 

My code is:

import org.gephi.project.api.ProjectController
ref = java.lang.Class.forName("org.gephi.project.api.ProjectController")

And I get: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gephi.project.api.ProjectController

Could you post your full code which returns ProjectControllerImpl and your JythonPath?

Comment: also one thing to look out for, in your code post the call to newProject() returns void should be pc.newProject() followed by workspace = pc.getCurrentWorkspace()

Comment: Well, the problem was not the class reference but the missing CLASSPATH. Adding the jar file to sys.path is not enough and one should also set the CLASS PATH like you say. My original code works in this case. Thanks again.